# How to make visible changes to GCC source code, specifically on the libitm?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am modifying a function from the **libitm** from GCC source code. I've just added some prints to it in order to test whether the modifications are visible. However, the prints never show. I am sure that the functions are being called, but the implementation with the added prints is not being used for some reason.

I had a similar problem to this one when I started modifying the **libstdc++-v3** and I solved it by adding the flag **-static-libstdc++**.

I am using:

1. make -j4
2. make install
3. ../install/bin/g++ -std=c++11 ../../file.cpp -o a -static-libstdc++
4. ./a

Is there any flag I am missing that is needed so that the modified implementation is used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to build and install your customized version of GCC. Either by replacing your existing version of GCC, or installing it side-by-side the existing version. In the later case you need to configure the GCC build according and you need to either need to change your `PATH` or use a full pathname when invoking GCC in order to use your customized version instead.

Comment: I think you're going to need to create minimal complete and verifiable example here. Include both `file.cpp` and at least one of changes you made. Show what both the output you expect and what you get instead. List the complete steps you use to configure, build and install, including what version of the GCC source you're using. Whatever your problem is, it's something you're not mentioning.